# Day, Month text input: intelligent regex on the month part?

Tags: regex

I have a date entry control on a UI. It auto-completes the date as numbers are typed.

Currently using:

```
\d{1,2}(\.|\/|-)\d{1,2}
```

Test on http://regexpal.com/ to see it working.

Basically 1 or 2 digits, followed by one of ./-, and 1 or 2 digits. e.g. 01/9, 1/2, 1/1,  will match

What I'm looking to do (and can't!):

**If the second set of digits (the Month part) is 0 or 1, need another digit**

**If the second set of digits is 2-9, match**

That's it basically, thanks

Brian

Comment: is your date going to be localized? in different localizations, second group doesn't not necessary represent month

Comment: Don't need to cater for localization at this point, or validation of the day or month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number ranges are a bit annoying in regex, and should maybe be done in a separate step, when the format is validated. But here is the regex:

```
\d{1,2}[/.-](0?[2-9]|1[0-2]|01|1[/.-])
```

That should match all the requirements (including the ones from the comments). Possible months:

```
2, 3, ..., 9
01, 02, 03, ..., 09
10, 11, 12
1/, 1., 1-
```

Comment: Tested on http://regexpal.com/, if I enter 1/1 shows as a match, but it should not match if the month is 1 or 0, it should expect another digit

Comment: Thanks, getting very close now:-) Just one issue, if user enters 1/1/ should match. So if month starts with 1 followed by any of /.- should match.

Comment: @BrianBishop I will simply not question these requirements. But you should really include an extensive list of examples into regex questions: `\d{1,2}(\.|\/|-)(0?[2-9]|1[0-2]|01|1[/.-])`